# Finding neighborhoods of zero, $\overline{N}$ and $\overset{\circ}{N}$ for the given topology on $\mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology

I have this topological exercise: le $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ a topological space such that $\tau$ is made by $\mathbb{R}$ and all the part of $\mathbb{R}$ which do not contain the number $3$

1) Find the sets of neighbourhood of $0$ and calculate $\overline{N}$ and $\overset{\circ}{N}$.

I say that $\mathcal{V}(0)=\{V\subset\mathbb{R}, \{0\}\subset V\}$ because $\{0\}$ is open

2)Find $\overline{\mathbb{N}},\overset{\circ}{\mathbb{N}}$

$\overline{\mathbb{N}}=\mathbb{N}$, $\overset{\circ}{\mathbb{N}}=\mathbb{N}\setminus\{3\}$ is it right ?

3) calculate the derivtive set $\mathbb{N}'$ : $x\in \mathbb{N}'\Longleftrightarrow \forall V\in \mathcal{V}_x, V\cap \mathbb{N}\neq\emptyset$

then I found that **$$\mathbb{N}'=\{3\}$$**

4) What is $\overline{A}$ for any set $A$ from $\mathbb{R}$

$x\in \overline{A}\Longleftrightarrow \forall V\in\mathcal{V}_x, V\cap A\neq \emptyset$ I think that $\overline{A}=A\cup\{3\}$ because the only ngbh of $3$ is $\mathbb{R}$ and $A\subset\overline{A}$

Are my answers are right?

Please thank you

Comment: This is not a single question: please enumerate all your questions in order not to get a confusing answer.

Comment: Please rewrite your question in a more intelligible way.

Comment: @D_S yes, in this topology. $3$ is not a member of $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\{0\}$ is open (as $3 \notin \{0\}$), so $0$ is an isolated point, and so $\mathcal{V}(0) = \{V \subseteq \mathbb{R}: 0 \in V\}$ (or equivalently $\{0\} \subseteq V$, but I find this less intuitive).

$\mathbb{N}$ is closed as it does contain $3$ (so its complement is then by definition open). So it indeed equals its closure.

Its interior is indeed $\mathbb{N} \setminus \{3\}$: this set is open and the largest open subset of the natural numbers (as we cannot add $3$, then we lose openness).

All points unequal to $3$ are isolated (see $0$ above) so are not in $\mathbb{N}'$, while the only neighbourhood of $3$ is $\mathbb{R}$, which intersects $\mathbb{N}$ (or any set that has a point different from $3$!) in a point different from $3$, so you're right that $\mathbb{N}' = \{3\}$.

If $A$ is any subset, then adding $3$ to it makes it closed (as then the complement does not contain $3$ any more). But note that the empty set is already closed. So $\overline{A} = A$ when $A = \emptyset$ and $\overline{A} = A \cup \{3\}$ if $A \neq \emptyset$.

So I agree with all your answers, except omitting the empty case in the last one.

[Added from comment] As to the sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$, it cannot converge to any isolated point (as all terms are different), so it cannot converge to any $x \neq 3$. $3$ has only one neighbourhood, namely $\mathbb{R}$, and this contains the whole sequence. So $a_n \rightarrow 3$ and only to $3$.

$a_n = n$, then no point $x \neq 3$ is an adherent point, and again $a_n \rightarrow 3$ (any sequence converges to $3$ in this topology!). So that is also the only adherent point.

Comment: Thank you, please can you help me in the same exercise : i have to study the nature of the sequence $(u_n)=(\frac1n)$ and the adherent value of the sequence $(v_n)=(n)$, I don't know how i must do

Comment: Thank you, please i want to find a basis for $\tau$ can i say that $B=\{\{x\in \mathbb{R} \setminus\{2012\}\},\mathbb{R}\}$ is a basis for $\tau$ please

Comment: No, all isolated points are in any base.

Comment: i must say  $B=\{\{x\},x\in\mathbb{R} \setminus\{3\}\}\cup\{\mathbb{R}\}$?

Comment: Why 2012? Make it 3 and I agree.

Comment: yes 3 i do a mistake